# A problem in integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$,  $f \in C^2[0,1]$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. For all $x\in (0,1)$, $f(x) > 0$. Indicate with $M = \max \limits_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$.

1. Prove that $\forall a,b \in [0,1]$,  $a<b$,
   $$
   \int_a^b \left| \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} \right| \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{1}{M} \vert f'(b) - f'(a)\vert.
   $$
2. Prove that
   $$
   \int_0^1 \left| \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} \right| \mathrm{d}x \geq 4.
   $$

The first half of the problem is easy to solve with Newton-Leibniz formula and basic properties of Riemann integral. I wonder the proof of 2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess it's possible to use Kolmogorov's inequality for $k = 2$. 
Actually, we should use $(\sup f'(x))^2 \le \sup f(x) \cdot \sup f''(x)$